# What do you call the cones used to mark a field for sport activities?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What do you call these cones used to mark a field for sports?

[image: a stack of green plastic cones]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More specific terms would include ***saucer cones*** ([1](https://youtu.be/0D1Dy3xLMvc?t=25s), [2](https://www.championsports.com/cones_saucer/)), ***disc cones*** ([1](https://youtu.be/le7EouXoH78?t=10s), [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HTOIUK)), and ***flat cones*** ([1](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Spalding-Flat-Cones-Orange-Yellow-20-Pack/32664885) – on the label it says ***marking discs***, [2](http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/primed-flat-cones-4-pack-16pmdu4pkfltcnxxxgaa/16pmdu4pkfltcnxxxgaa)), if you wish to distinguish them from [***safety cones*** or ***traffic cones***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_cone).

Comment: The general category is often called "training cones", or maybe "cone markers" or "marker cones". Not sure if the OP was trying to ask how to identify this specific variety as opposed to other training cones, or just more generally. See for example [the soccer training cone category on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Soccer-Training-Cones/b?ie=UTF8&node=5680905011&sa-no-redirect=1). (And in my experience, when you're actually using them on a field, everyone just calls them cones.)

Answer (score 11):

Calling them **cones** is the most obvious choice, "place the **cones**", "mark the field with **cones**" etc.

You might also refer to them as **markers** or **marks**.

[Marker - a sign that shows where something is, Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/marker).

They also could be named according to the sport they are used in e.g. a *goal* might be marked out with two red cones - you would likely refer to the pair as a *goal* as the usage of cones is already obvious.

Answer (score -1):

These are normally called **field markers**, or **marking disc** in general language.